# How fix SMTP connection from an Azure Website?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Actually we have our website in WindowsAzure.

Its a Classic ASP site and its configured as a "Standard WebSite", 32Bit platform and its working with our domain.

As a traditional web, it uses a SMTP server to send email (ie. contacts from contact page).

We know Azure don´t provide SMTP server so we have tried with all these service with no luck:

- RackSpace
- Mandrill App
- SendGrid (Recommended here).

For all of them, we are getting this error: "**The transport failed to connect to the server.**"

How we can fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Whatever you are doing and failing is not related to the providers you tried. We successfully used mandrill as well as sendgrid on Azure Websites and Web role projects. Does it work when you run your project locally? Have you tried not using port 25 (I don't know about Azure but some hosting providers have messed with filtering that port).

Comment: Thanks Simon. We have tried with all ports: 25, 487 and 465 (and with Sendgrid and Mandrill). 
Also we are sure the code is right because it is working in the old hosting (he moved from it to Azure this weekend). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don´t know why but suddenly it begins to work.

The only change we did in the Azure config was putting ON the WebSockets but we think it was the solution.

We left the Mandrill smtp Server.